# Format not available in tag wiki excerpt

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

For example, [table](/questions/tagged/table): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table?sort=faq

Format like **bold** or *italic* are not available , so it leaves ugly text there:

```
**This tag is *extremely* ambiguous. Consider using other tags instead.**
```

Does this need to get fixed, or it's not supported and the tag-wiki needs to be format-free?

Comment: As there is no option for format, it would be better to remove all these `*`.