# Is it possible to use simple markup (particularly italics) in tag wiki excerpts?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, tag-wiki-excerpt

For the purposes of titles, in particular on sites like Sci-Fi & Fantasy, Literature, and Movies & TV, is it possible to allow basic markdown appropriate for titles (*italics*) in the tag wiki excerpts?

I was recently editing a tag wiki on Movies & TV and realized that the markdown does not work in the excerpts so I'm forced to either leave titles without appropriate text decoration (which is what is generally done on both sites) or to use quotes. Neither of these solutions are "correct".

[image: Sci-Fi Screenshot of Tag Wiki Excerpt]
[image: Movies&TV Screenshot of Tag Wiki Excerpt]

Is it possible to allow italics specifically on sites that warrant it by having a large volume of book, film, or TV show titles as tags? Or is this something not possible due to how the excerpts work?

This is a very specific request to be only used in very special cases and most likely would not be enabled on all Stack Exchage sites. I understand that, in general, markdown is not popular for tag wiki excerpts but I think that it may be worth making an exception if it is beneficial for clarity.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: No, that's not a dupe, as I understand it; this question should really be about asking for a change. (Catija, perhaps editing to clarify that this is a feature-request would be good.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy You're right. Edited.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62614/tag-wiki-summary-does-not-allow-markup http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts

Comment: @random That is not the same question at all and it **doesn't** have an answer.

Comment: Which one? There are at least three that cover the same request

Comment: @random the one actually marked as the duplicate. Also, none of those questions specifically relate to titles and most of them are **bugs**, not feature requests.

Comment: Two of them are feature requests for simple formatting, one is a bug, all say that's not going to happen

Comment: The main one you've used as the direct duplicate is a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189468/format-not-available-in-tag-wiki-excerpt) but has no answer and the one it's a [dupe of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138023/tag-links-in-tag-excerpts-not-shown-properly) is a bug. Both of the feature requests are duplicates and were made dupes of "bug" notices.... which doesn't make sense to me as the point of a feature request is to ask for a change. I'm not even asking for a broad change, just a very specific one.

Comment: This would be nice for the natural language sites as well, where italics are used for the use–mention distinction.

Comment: Just a quick check: Would the markdown options similar to what is available in comments be enough?

Comment: @rene Even that's more than I'm asking for, so sure. Specifically not interested in links, for example.